# How to make a form responsive (show/hide portion of the form) based on the selected items from a drop down list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a razor view in a c# mvc project, & i would like the items(text boxes and etc) to be responsive based on the selected values from a drop down list.

This is the drop down in my razor view:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(a=> a.pm_main_rep.PM_Event_CategoriesId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a=>a.pm_main_rep.PM_Event_CategoriesId, new SelectList(Model.pm_evt_catgrss, "Id","type_of_event"), "Select a category", new { @class="form-control"})
</div>
```

Now this drop down populates some values from database as meeting, training and etc.

All i want at the moment is that the below textbox which is used for picking the date should appear if the user selects meeting from the above dropdown.

```
    @if(?????)
    {
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(a => a.pm_main_rep.Estimated_Start_Date)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.pm_main_rep.Estimated_Start_Date, "Start Date", new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", @style = "cursor :default;" })
    </div> 
    }
```

What should be the logic inside the if() block, or if there is a better approach please tell me guys.
Thanks

Comment: `@if(..)` is razor code - its executed on the server before you send the view to the client. If you want to respond to client side events then you need to use javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options - depend on **where** you want to do the action, in the server side or in the client side. I recommend to use the server side if there is many data to send the client for each choice, and the client side, which does not require to do a request to the server, otherwise.

1) In the server side, you should post the form every time the user selects an other option from the list. I display how to do this via ajax with sending HTML from the server, but you also can send JSON from the server and parse it with js. I'm using jquery:

js:

```
$('#Estimated_Start_Date').change(function() {
  $.post('/.../gethtmlfordropdown', { selection: $('#Estimated_Start_Date').val() }, function(html) {
    $('#Choice').html(html);
  });
});
```

cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(a=> a.pm_main_rep.PM_Event_CategoriesId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a=>a.pm_main_rep.PM_Event_CategoriesId, new SelectList(Model.pm_evt_catgrss, "Id","type_of_event"), "Select a category", new { @class="form-control"})
</div>
<div id="Choice"><!-- Content from ajax --></div>
```

server:

```
public ActionResult GetHtmlForDropDown(string selection)
{
    string html = ...; // Get the html depending on 'selection'
    return PartialView(html);
}
```

2) In the client side - give ids to each content, it'll be easier if the id will be equal to the value of the selection in teh dropdown, or something like:

cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(a=> a.pm_main_rep.PM_Event_CategoriesId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a=>a.pm_main_rep.PM_Event_CategoriesId, new SelectList(Model.pm_evt_catgrss, "Id","type_of_event"), "Select a category", new { @class="form-control"})
</div>
<div class="choice" id="Value1" style="display: none;">...</div>
<div class="choice" id="Value2" style="display: none;">...</div>
<div class="choice" id="Value3" style="display: none;">...</div>
```

js:

```
$('#Estimated_Start_Date').change(function() {
  var selection = $('#Estimated_Start_Date').val();
  $('.choice').css({ 'display': 'none' })
    .filter('#' + selection).css({ 'display': 'block' });
});
```